# Assign groups in pandas dataframe based on column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like below :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2'], 'P':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


         |     A      |    P      | 
         +------------+-----------+
         |    ABCD_1  |    1      | 
         |    ABCD_1  |    0      |  
         |    ABCD_1  |    0      |  
         |    ABCD_1  |    0      | 
         |    PQRS_2  |    0      | 
         |    PQRS_2  |    1      | 
         |    PQRS_2  |    0      | 
         |    PQRS_2  |    0      |
         |    PQRS_2  |    0      |
         +------------+-----------+
```

I want to group the strings as per Column A in `df` and assign the groups to new column G in the same dataframe `df` in pandas (python). I'm expecting the output like below.

```
     |     A      |    P      |     G      |
     +------------+-----------+------------+
     |    ABCD_1  |    1      |            |
     |    ABCD_1  |    0      |            |
     |    ABCD_1  |    0      |      1     |
     |    ABCD_1  |    0      |            |
     +------------|-----------|------------+
     |    PQRS_2  |    0      |            |
     |    PQRS_2  |    1      |            |
     |    PQRS_2  |    0      |      2     |
     |    PQRS_2  |    0      |            |
     |    PQRS_2  |    0      |            |
     +------------+-----------+------------+
```

So how can I achieve this using pandas and python ? Thanks !

Comment: can you share the data in list/dict format, so that we can directly read the data

Comment: Have just edited my post to add the data in list/dict format
```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2'], 'P':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: `df['G'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0] + 1`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar : Thanks for the solution - I'm not expecting column G to be a index of the dataframe but rather as a column itself. I want to display column G similar to the way you showed up column G as index in the solution.

Comment: @user3046211 then don't apply the index, would that work fine for you? let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: @user3046211 so my existing solution does work for you right?

Comment: If I don't apply that as an index, then it would show all the 1's and 2's for the two groups. Instead of showing all the 1's and 2's I just want to show only one value (1's and 2's) per group just like I mentioned in the post. So is it possible to show in pandas df ?

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible, hoever you can replace those other values as Nan or empty string, do you want that solution?

Comment: Sure, that works :)
Quick question - Can we not take the average of each of the group's values and then assign the average value as a column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.split.html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.htm) to get the desired output

##### Creating data

```
data = {'A': ['ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'ABCD_1', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2', 'PQRS_2'], 'P':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Pre-processing

```
df['G'] = df.['A'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
```

##### Generating output

```
df.set_index(['G', 'A'])
```

##### Output

This gives us the expected output:

```
          P
G A        
1 ABCD_1  1
  ABCD_1  0
  ABCD_1  0
  ABCD_1  0
2 PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  1
  PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  0
```

##### Alternatively :

You can also use [`pandas.factorize.html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to for obtaining a numeric representation of an array when all we need is distinct values

```
df['G'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0] + 1
df.set_index(['G', 'A'])
```

This gives you the same output :

```
          P
G A        
1 ABCD_1  1
  ABCD_1  0
  ABCD_1  0
  ABCD_1  0
2 PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  1
  PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  0
  PQRS_2  0
```

**EDIT :** But as we discussed, you don't need index on the column but a single instance of the value for the column `G` and not the other values duplicated.

We can replace all duplicated values of the column with a empty string. We can use [`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) which returns us boolean Series denoting duplicate rows.

```
df['G'] = pd.factorize(df['A'])[0] + 1
df['G'].astype('str')
df.loc[df['G'].duplicated(), 'G'] = ''
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
        A  P  G
0  ABCD_1  1  1
1  ABCD_1  0   
2  ABCD_1  0   
3  ABCD_1  0   
4  PQRS_2  0  2
5  PQRS_2  1   
6  PQRS_2  0   
7  PQRS_2  0   
8  PQRS_2  0
```